# $ \lim _{x \rightarrow 1}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{1-x^{3}}\right) = ? $

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 1}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{1-x^{3}}\right)
$$

I am trying to evaluate this and so far this is what i have done -

$$
\lim _{x \rightarrow 1}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{1-x^{3}}\right) = 
\lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\left({1-x}\right)\left(1+x^2+x-3\right)}{\left(1-x\right)\left(1-x^3\right)}\right)
$$
From above, I cancel out (1-x) from denominator and numerator.

$$= \lim _{x\to 1}\left(\frac{\left(x-1\right)\left(x+2\right)}{\left(1-x\right)\left(1+x+x^2\right)}\right)$$

Now I am stuck how to proceed further as x $\rightarrow 1$ .

Comment: you can cancel out another $(1-x)$

Comment: in the last line, factor out $-1$ from $(x-1)$ in the numerator and cancel it with the $(1-x)$ in the denominator. Also, you should have $(1+x+x^2)$ in the denominator in the last line.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be $1+x+x^2,$ not $1+x+x^3?$

Comment: Thank you @ThomasAndrews @C Squared , Fixed!

Comment: The next step is just that, for $x\neq 1,$ $$\frac{x-1}{1-x}=-1.$$

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2297504/72031

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next step is just that, for $x\neq 1,$ $$\frac{x-1}{1-x}=-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick you can use: substitute x as 1+h  as lim h tends to zero and then solve algebra . In the end all the 'h' terms  will be zeros and you will get answer as 1

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.